# Order By with Union Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, union

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReport]
        @FromDate DATETIME = NULL,
        @ToDate DATETIME = NULL,
        @TenantID int ,
        @BusinessUnitId int
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @listStr Varchar(max), @listValue Varchar(max)

  Select 
     @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + FieldLabel 
  From 
     (Select Distinct Top 100 
         FieldLabel, ControlTypeId 
      From 
         PaymentCustomFieldDefinitions PCFD
      Inner Join 
         Product P On P.Id = PCFD.ProductId
      Where 
         P.TenantId = @TenantId
      Order By 
         ControlTypeId Desc) R

   Set @listStr = ',' + @listStr
   Set @listStr = IsNull(@listStr, '')

   Select       
       'Confirmation Number,Business Unit,Bank Account,Merchant Account,Product Name,Payment Date,Payment Time,Total Amount,Status,First Name,Last Name,Payment Method' + @listStr  
   Union
   SELECT       
      p.ConfirmationNumber + ',' + bu.Name + ',' + p.TenantBankAccountName + ',' + Case When ma.Name IS NULL then '' ELSE ma.Name END  + ',' + pd.Name + ',' + 
      cast(P.PaymentDate as Varchar(11)) + ',' + convert(VARCHAR(8), P.PaymentDate,108) + ',' + Cast(p.TotalDue As Varchar(20)) + ',' + p.PaymentStatusText + ',' + p.PayorFirstName + ',' + p.PayorLastName + ',' + p.PaymentMethodText + ',' + [dbo].[GetPaymentReferenceAndCustomFields](p.Id,@listStr) 
   FROM 
      Payment p 
   INNER JOIN 
      Product pd ON p.ProductId = pd.Id
   INNER JOIN 
      BusinessUnit bu ON pd.BusinessUnitId = bu.Id 
   INNER JOIN 
      ProductDetailPayment pdp ON p.ProductId = pdp.ProductId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      MerchantAccount ma ON  ma.Id = pdp.MerchantAccountId   
   WHERE 
      p.PaymentDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
      AND p.TenantId = @TenantId  AND pd.BusinessUnitId= @BusinessUnitId
   ORDER BY 
      p.ProductId desc
END
```

Getting this error when using `Order by` :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spReport, Line 41
>   The multi-part identifier "p.ProductId" could not be bound.
>   Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spQueryPaymentDetailReport, Line 41
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference `p.ProductId` in the ORDER BY because the first subquery doesn't have a `p` dataset.

You can't reference a `ProductId` column in the ORDER BY because there's no column by that name in the combined result set.

To solve these issues, you could add a `ProductId` column and, if the final output must contain a single column like in your query, use a derived table:

```
SELECT
  p.CSV
FROM (
    Select
        ProductId = 2147483647,
        CSV = 'Confirmation Number,Business Unit,Bank Account,Merchant Account,Product Name,Payment Date,Payment Time,Total Amount,Status,First Name,Last Name,Payment Method' + @listStr
    Union
    SELECT
       p.ProductId,
       p.ConfirmationNumber + ',' + bu.Name + ',' + p.TenantBankAccountName + ',' + Case When ma.Name IS NULL then '' ELSE ma.Name END  + ',' + pd.Name + ',' +
       cast(P.PaymentDate as Varchar(11)) + ',' + convert(VARCHAR(8), P.PaymentDate,108) + ',' + Cast(p.TotalDue As Varchar(20)) + ',' + p.PaymentStatusText + ',' + p.PayorFirstName + ',' + p.PayorLastName + ',' + p.PaymentMethodText + ',' + [dbo].[GetPaymentReferenceAndCustomFields](p.Id,@listStr)
    FROM
       Payment p
    INNER JOIN
       Product pd ON p.ProductId = pd.Id
    INNER JOIN
       BusinessUnit bu ON pd.BusinessUnitId = bu.Id
    INNER JOIN
       ProductDetailPayment pdp ON p.ProductId = pdp.ProductId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
       MerchantAccount ma ON  ma.Id = pdp.MerchantAccountId
    WHERE
       p.PaymentDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
       AND p.TenantId = @TenantId  AND pd.BusinessUnitId= @BusinessUnitId
) p
ORDER BY
   p.ProductId desc
;
```

The first row is assigned the `MaxInt` ID value because, as I understand, it is the header row and must go first according to the specified `ORDER BY p.ProductId DESC` clause (and because I've assumed the `ProductId` is an `int`, of course).